# Closed Solution

Tags: equation-solving

Is it possible to find a closed solution for the following system of equations?

```
    sqrdn = 1/
   18 (2 (1 - 2 nu) (Sqrt[3] sig1 + Sqrt[3] sig2 + Sqrt[3] sig3 - 
        3 xi)^2 + (1 + nu) (3 sig2 - 3 sig3 + (
        6 Sin[beta] (-Sqrt[3] c Cos[phi] + xi Sin[phi]))/(
        Cos[beta] (1 + Sin[phi]) - (-1 + Sin[phi]) Sin[
           beta + \[Pi]/6]))^2 + 
     3 (1 + nu) (-2 sig1 + sig2 + sig3 + (
        2 Cos[beta] (3 c Cos[phi] - Sqrt[3] xi Sin[phi]))/(
        Cos[beta] (1 + Sin[phi]) - (-1 + Sin[phi]) Sin[
           beta + \[Pi]/6]))^2);
eq1 = D[sqrdn, xi] == 0;
eq2 = D[sqrdn, beta] == 0;
Reduce[{eq1, eq2}, {xi, beta}]
```

knowing that `sig1 >= sig2 >= sig3`

Comment: What you mean by: " closed solution" ?

Comment: I mean Analytical solution.

Comment: You might try the substitution in `eq1` and `eq2`, `{Cos[beta]->c,Sin[beta]->s}` and solve for `{s,c,xi}` with the constraint `c^2+s^2==1`

Comment: And the term `Sin[beta + \[Pi]/6]`?

Comment: Use `TrigExpand`

Comment: @mikado this keep running forever:

Comment: `eq11 = TrigExpand[eq1] /. {Cos[beta] -> c, Sin[beta] -> s, 
    Sin[phi] -> sinphi};
eq22 = TrigExpand[eq2] /. {Cos[beta] -> c, Sin[beta] -> s, 
    Sin[phi] -> sinphi};
Solve[{eq11, eq22, c^2 + s^2 == 1}, {c, s, xi}]`

Comment: I would try substituting numerical values for some or all of the parameters and see if the equations become soluble

Comment: Substituting numerical values is not working either.

Comment: I can solve this equation numerically, but I'm interested in the analytical solution of it. If possible...